# What is the meaning of weigh in the phrase "get under weigh"?

Tags: word-meaning

What is the meaning of  the word weigh in the phrase "get under way".though dictionary suggest that it is way, but i failed to understand how "weigh" became "way".

Comment: I'd say it's an "eggcorn / mishmash" conflation of ***get under way*** (start moving, many contexts) and ***weigh anchor*** (nautical, raise the anchor so a ship can move). Which only really applies to the *written* form anyway, since in speech they're indistinguishable.

Answer (score 3):

It is *way* - if you have seen it written as *weigh*, that is an error. A ship is said to be *under way* when it is moving through the water. According to Oxford Languages, this expression goes back to the 18th century and comes from the Dutch word *onderweg*, meaning *on the way!*

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary labels “under weigh” a common variant of “under way” that arose “from erroneous association with the phr. ‘to weigh anchor.’ ”. In most dictionaries, the “variant” label means the spelling is acceptable in standard English, unless a more restrictive label, like “dialect” or “slang” or “offensive,” is also appended. The earliest example given of 'under way' is  1743, and  of 'under weigh' is 1777. The _Pequod_, the ship that appears in the 1851 novel _Moby-Dick_ by American author Herman Melville got 'under weigh'. However, I agree that it is best avoided.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey can I say "I am on my weigh to the supermarket"?

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, 'under weigh', the entire phrase, seems to be considered an erroneous or acceptable (OED) variant of 'under way' in connection with boats, ships, etc.